# Maximum amount of memory that can be leaked for iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad

I was wondering what is the maximum amount of leaks an iOS app can have - I'm currently testing my app with Instruments, and have a few leaks here and there but the app doesn't crash. Is 1MB acceptable?

Comment: There is no max leakage that is acceptable. Just like a pipe under your sink, fix it !!!

Comment: Funny question. lol. I would recommend to take as much time as needed to improve your memory management skills and detect your leaks with instruments. When you get to develop big projects it might not be only 1 MB!.

Comment: Hmm not really the answers i was looking for but i guess i'll have to fix them all

Comment: How bout a 3.12KB leak ? When used for 10 mins :x

Answer (score 0):

As @Romain commented,

#### No leaks are acceptable!

Just like if you found out the nuclear reactor beside your house was leaking radioactive material (but the owners assured you it was fine), it better get fixed!

If you absolutely must have leaks, I.e. they only happen on startup and you can't feasibly fix them, then 3.12KB should be fine.

If, on the other hand, it *is* a 3.12KB leak *every ten minutes*, then it must be fixed.

Imagine someone using your app for several hours start straight - or multitasking and never force killing your app. Eventually that 3.12KB is going to turn into 3.12GB - and that is *never* acceptable.